# put a view over another view

Tags: android, user-interface, quickaction

hi i create a quick action similar that's you see in the below picture.
[image]

but this is not my desired form. i like my quick action be similar this:

[image]

i create my quickaction from tutorial that create quickAction that u can see in the above pic.
now i have a question:
how can i pull down image view that my quickAction be similar second image?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put a negative bottom margin on the ImageView:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
```